# display data from mongodb with webix

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webix

I'm new in javascript and I want to use webix.
I saw the get started and it's Ok...

So, my problem is that I can't display data from mongodb.

This is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//connect to the mongo
var db = require('mongoskin').db("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", { w: 0});
db.bind('sites');

//create the app instance
var app = express();
//serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//parse POST data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// // parse application/json
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

function after_update(err, res, record){
  if (err){
    res.status(500);
    res.send({ error:err.toString() });
  } else {
    res.send(record || {});
  }
}

//data loading
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
  db.record.find().toArray(function(err, data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      data[i].id = data[i]._id;
      delete data[i]._id;
    }

    res.send(data);
  });
});

app.post('/data', function(req, res){
  db.record.insert(req.body, function(err, record){
    if (err) return res.send({ status:"error" });
    res.send({ newid:req.body._id });
  });
});
app.put('/data/:id', function(req, res){
  db.record.updateById(req.param("id"), req.body, function(err){
    if (err) return res.send({ status:"error" });
    res.send({});
  });
});
app.delete('/data/:id', function(req, res){
  db.record.removeById(req.param("id"), req.body, function(err){
    if (err) return res.send({ status:"error" });
    res.send({});
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and I'm using index.html to display data. Here that it sucks. 
my problem is that I can't found the right manner to get the data from my table in mongodb.
I want to display the cars in my DB.

who has an exemple that can help?

Anyone can help please?
Thank you

Comment: display sites not cars

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the "/data" in the browser. If it shows the valid JSON, check the client-side code of the datatable, it must be something like following

```
{ view:"datatable", autoConfig:true, url:"/data" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in your code (i guess that your collection is **"cars"** becouse your text):

1. You are binding a diferent collection than "cars", in the line *"db.bind('sites');"*. You should change for *"db.bind('cars');"*
2. You are using the collection "record" to retrieve and write data, in the sentences *"db.record.find", "db.record.insert", "db.record.updateById"* and *"db.record.removeById"*. You should change for *"db.cars.find", "db.cars.insert", "db.cars.updateById"* and *"db.cars.removeById"*.

Cheers.